# BusyIndicator in WPF using UserControl and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

The busy indicator does not seem to work. I am setting IsBusy flag to true before loading data and false once loading data is finished
but the indicator does not appear. Following is my code snippit.

```
<UserControl ...
xmlns:WPFTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FormLoadCompleteCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

 <Grid>

    .... 

    <WPFTool:BusyIndicator Name="BusyInd" BusyContent="Loading Servers" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>


public class MyViewModelForUserControl : ViewModelBase
{

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy { get { return _isBusy; } set { _isBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy"); } }


    private DelegateCommand _formLoadCompleteCommand;
    public DelegateCommand FormLoadCompleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_formLoadCompleteCommand == null)
                _formLoadCompleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(FormLoadComplete);
            return _formLoadCompleteCommand;
        }
    }


    private void FormLoadComplete(object parameter)
    {   
        IsBusy = true;
        LoadData();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `LoadData()` synchronous (please add it to the question)? You are blocking UI for a duration, so no changes to `IsBusy` will be rendered by the view, only last one (`IsBusy = false;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void FormLoadComplete(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            LoadData();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => IsBusy = false);
        });
    }
```

You have to leave the first event handler and run `LoadData` not on the UI thread.

Comment: I assume you meant Application.Current.Dispatcher, if so this also does not work. I waits for FormLoadComplete to finish.

Comment: try run Task.Run(()=>LoadData()) and at the end of LoadData{ ..Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> IsBusy = false;); }